# "everybody" vs "everybody else"

Tags: phrase-usage, pronouns

I know the difference between **everybody** and **everybody else**, but can sometimes everybody implies everybody else?

For example

> She didn't know what she said was a faux pas until **everybody else** stopped talking and looked at her strangely.

Can I say **everybody** only to imply **everybody else** in above sentence?
Is it understandable but strange, or is it just fine and normal, or totally unacceptable?

BTW, in my native language, it's perfectly fine just to say "everybody" to me.

Comment: "Everyone" may be more fitting in your example.

Comment: @lurker So it's a bit strange not because of meaning, but because no one will use everybody in this case?

Comment: Sorry, mate. "Everybody else" is acceptable, and not strange. I should have added that bit the first time. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **everyone**, **everybody**, or **everybody else** in this sentence with no change in meaning. **Else** emphasizes that each individual person stopped talking.